# error in a user loading controller for excel, but it is an error that does not throw a status

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

From the front an Excel file is loaded with around 50 to 100 users, some cases may be more, however the problem lies in the fact that, after loading a third of the users, the following error is thrown.

POST /api/loadXLSX/ - - ms - -

which causes the front to issue an alert saying that there was a problem but the back continues to iterate the users after that error.

I'm not sure how to handle the error since I don't know if it's a settimeout or what?

The error is not shown if there are between 0 and 50 users, but when there are more, at some point the error is thrown.

We cannot lower the number of users since the company wants it to be massive and fast.

Comment: "*POST /api/loadXLSX/ - - ms - -*" This is not an error message, and by itself does not necessarily indicate a problem of any sort. It's likely an informational line of some sort of log.

Comment: "*the company wants it to be massive and fast.*" Excel is 100% the completely wrong tool for this then, full stop. Beyond 1 concurrent user of an Excel file, you're way better off investing your time into using a proper database and frontend instead.

Comment: Please provide your code as a [mre] so that others can reproduce your issue. See also [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.